# How to change prop value with another function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have one component in my NextJs App and I want to change child prop (In here named as `type`) of child component when `<input>` element is `null`

But I can't do that. Somebody want to help me thanks.

```js
"use client";
import { Icon } from "@iconify/react";
import "./_input-fragment.scss";

const InputFragment = (props) => {
  let variable;


  const checkVal = (value) => { // Everythink OK in this here.
    if (!value) {
      setData("error");
    }
  };

  const setData = (val) => {
    return (variable = val);
  };

  const Icn = (props) => {
    alert(props.type);
    if (props.type == "error") {
      return (
        <Icon
          icon="ph:seal-warning-fill"
          color="red"
        />
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="input-fragment">
        <label htmlFor={props.labelFor}>
          {props.labelName}
          <input
            id={props.labelFor}
            name={props.label}
            type={props.inputType}
            min={props.minLength}
            max={props.maxLength}
            defaultValue={"John Doe"}
            onBlur={() =>
              checkVal(document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value) <!-- When `input` is changed return value of `<input>` element to `checkVal()` function. -->
            }
          />
        </label>
        <Icn type={variable} /> // Dynamic update doesn't work.
      </div>
      <p className="message"></p>
    </>
  );
};

export default InputFragment;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your component does not re-render.
I think you can use useState hook in this case.

```
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Icon } from "@iconify/react";
import "./_input-fragment.scss";

const InputFragment = (props) => {
  const [variable, setVariable] = useState("");


  const checkVal = (value) => { // Everythink OK in this here.
    setVariable(value ? "": "error");
  };

  const Icn = () => {
    alert(variable);
    if (variable === "error") {
      return (
        <Icon
          icon="ph:seal-warning-fill"
          color="red"
        />
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="input-fragment">
        <label htmlFor={props.labelFor}>
          {props.labelName}
          <input
            id={props.labelFor}
            name={props.label}
            type={props.inputType}
            min={props.minLength}
            max={props.maxLength}
            defaultValue={"John Doe"}
            onBlur={(e) =>
              checkVal(e.target.value)
            }
          />
        </label>
        <Icn /> // Dynamic update doesn't work.
      </div>
      <p className="message"></p>
    </>
  );
};

export default InputFragment;
```